# Gearmand autostart at system boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, gearman, autorun

Gearman server is installed and working fine on Ubuntu 12.04. But it won`t start at system boot.
I try this:

1. Startup applications (/etc/init.d/gearman-job-server owned by root),
2. sudo update-rc.d gearman-job-server defaults
3. Into rc.local added (I try this line with `sh` and without)

   ```
   sh /etc/init.d/gearman-job-server start 
   exit 0
   ```

No effect! gearman not start after reboot. But it works fine if I run it manually by

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/gearman-job-server start
```

Please, help me!